# How to check initial data when save model in ModelAdmin?

Tags: python, django, admin

I use `save_model()` method in `ModelAdmin`.

I want to do sth when specific field changed (i.e. `staus`). 
So I want to know initial data before save admin so I could check it in `save_model`.

I knew that there's `__init__` and `__save__` method in `Model` itself, but I want to activate code only in ModelAdmin.

Here's sample code below

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if obj.status != xxx (intial data?) and obj.status == 7:
        # do sth
    super(CustomAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

#### Summary

- Can I know initial data from obj after save in admin?
- Is there any way to do sth when only saving in admin site?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) (pre_save)

Comment: @Gahan Thanks for comment. I'm afraid that it's impossible that object is save from admin with signals, right?

Comment: the logic is your model instance is created or updated in any condition it will call save method and signal will run if you have defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution!

I can know all changed data by `form.changed_data`, so I can do sth when specific field is in `form.changed_data`.

like this

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if 'status' in form.changed_data:
        if obj.status != xxx (intial data?) and obj.status == 7:
        # do sth
    super(CustomAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

I hope it will help somebody!

Comment: Also I've found out that if you need initial values of the changed fields they are stored in form.initial

Comment: @AlexanderAbdulov one was the answer :)